# Javascript - Define object property name by reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm trying to set some properties inside an object. I'd love not having to tell the object what to expect from the outside (making the object more flexible, imo), so I tried this, without success :

```
slideshow = {
    init : function(data) {
        if (!data)
            return false;

        $.each(data,
            function(index, value) {
                // this isn't working, and don't know how to
                this[index] = value;
            }
        );

        alert(this.options.interval);

        return true;
    },
};
```

Think it's pretty clear what's missing.

Any ideas? Cheers!

**update**

```
    var data = {
        options : [
            {
                interval : 8000,
                target : '#slider img',
            },
        ],
        images : [
            {
                img : 'assets/img/assets/img/slider_test_img.png',
                title : 'Uniforme de Restauração 1',
                description : 'blablabla descricao',
                url : 'http://www.google.pt',
            },
            {
                img : 'assets/img/assets/img/slider_test_img.png',
                title : 'Uniforme de Restauração 2',
                description : 'blablabla descricao 2',
                url : 'http://www.google.pt',
            },
            {
                img : 'assets/img/assets/img/slider_test_img.png',
                title : 'Uniforme de Restauração 3',
                description : 'blablabla descricao 3',
                url : 'http://www.google.pt',
            },
        ],
    }
```

Comment: You may want to consider setting sensible defaults if possible so that users can pass in a minimal set of parameters.

Comment: @Endophage I understand what you mean, and will to, but I'd also like to have freedom to latter update the object almost on the fly by passing new functions with `data` object.

Comment: and you should have that freedom.  Any default should be overridden by parameters the user can pass in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make a direct reference to the object:

```
$.each(data,
    function(index, value) {
     //     v------direct reference
        slideshow[index] = value;
    }
);
```

or don't use `$.each()`, and just use a `for-in` loop for an object, or a `for` for an array, since that won't change the `this` value:

```
  // I don't know if data is an Array or an object
for( var n in data ) {
    this[ n ] = data[ n ];
}
```

Or you could use the [`jQuery.proxy()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method to establish the `this` value in the `$.each()` handler.

```
$.each(data,
    $.proxy( function(index, value) {
        this[index] = value;
    }, this )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, all I needed and some extra usefull info too :) Cheers!

Comment: Just one thing, objects passed in ´data´ are being attached to the current object as arrays instead of regular object properties. Any thoughts?

Comment: Found a way using eval, not sure if it's wise though.

Comment: @yoda: I'd have to see what `data` is to know. Could you give an example of what `data` looks like? ...No, `eval()` is almost certainly not the solution.

Comment: Nevermind @patrick dw, found my problem to be just lack of attention :)

Comment: If using *for..in*, always remember to check the property with a *hasOwnProperty* test unless you want inherited enumerable properties copied as well.

Comment: If enumerating an object literal, that's only necessary if you're including code that extends `Object.prototype` with enumerable properties, a practice I'd advise against.

Answer (score 6):

You have to keep a reference to `this`:

```
var self = this;
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    self[index] = value;
});
```

or using jQuery's [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method:

```
$.each(data, $.proxy(function(index, value) {
    this[index] = value;
}, this));
```

Otherwise, `this` will refer to `value`, as described in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that inside the function that you pass to `each`, `this` no longer refers to `slideshow` but to the `value` of the current iteration. you need to store a reference to slideshow before going into the each loop:

```
slideshow = {
    init : function(data) {
        if (!data)
            return false;

        var that = this;

        $.each(data,
            function(index, value) {
                that[index] = value;
            }
        );
    },
};
```